# jcreator enter and numberformatexception

Tags: java, exception, enter, jcreator

Good day, I currently need help. The problem is that, i shifted to a new IDE which is JCreator, i have problems in the input of my program.

The program is simple, it just needs to store two inputs of integer on two different variables, the program is working with no exceptions if i'm executing it on other IDEs and command prompt but in JCreator, there is an exception that occurs whenever i enter a 2nd number

I need help, i can't switch IDEs for personal reasons, i've tried using the trim() method but the exception still happens, what should i do?

Thank you in advance and more power

```
import java.io.*;

public class InputError{
    public static void main(String [] args)throws IOException{
        BufferedReader x = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(x.readLine());
        int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(x.readLine());

    }
}
```

Exception part:

```
--------------------Configuration: TrialAgain - JDK version 1.8.0_66 <Default> - <Default>--------------------
1
19

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at InputError.main(InputError.java:8)

Process completed.
```

Comment: is there a reason why you dont use the Scanner class?

Comment: I want to participate on a local programming competition and the jdk version wasn't specified, I want to use an older version of jdk specifically jdk 1.4.3 just to be sure, the scanner wasn't available way back then but hopefully the jdk that will be used is somewhat newer like 8 so that I can use other methods of gathering input on a program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason JCreator takes an extra input from the buffer. One solution is to print an extra line just after the readLine().

```
BufferedReader x = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s = x.readLine();
System.out.println();
int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(s);
s = x.readLine();
System.out.println();
int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class InputError{
public static void main(String [] args){

    string B = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("first number");
    int b=Integer.parseInt(B);
    string A = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("second number");
    int a= Integer.parseInt(A);
    }
}
```